Feign client discovery with local server
Most of the microservices my team develops also provide Feign clients for easy integration.
When having to test a scenario when a service has to call another service using such a client we define mock endpoints for them using Wiremock (@AutoConfigureWireMock(port = 0) with WireMockApplicationListener) and then point the client at them by defining instances in application.yml using the spring.cloud.discovery.client.simple prefix and using localhost and the ${wiremock.server.port} placeholder for the port.
The problem is that we can't find a way to define such an instance for the endpoints provided by the service itself using @SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT) when using its own Feign client because that instance would have to use the ${local.server.port} variable instead, but that gets initialized at a much later phase by ServerPortInfoApplicationContextInitializer and the binding of properties has already happened.
spring.cloud.discovery.client.simple.instances:
  clientWithWiremockTarget:
    - uri: http://localhost:${wiremock.server.port} # works
  clientWithLocalTestServerTarget:
    - uri: http://localhost:${local.server.port} # does not work

Any idea?
Thank you
